# Run time error -2145320931 Object referenced by other objects

Tags: vba, runtime-error, autocad

i am trying to delete the layer in autocad with vba. i got runtime error -2145320931(8021001d) "Object is referenced by other objects.

- Layer which i going to delete doesn't belong to any entity.
- Layer name which i going to delete doesn't 0 and not a active layer.

thanks in advance

Comment: You will probably need to provide some more info so this question does not get closed.  Specifically, the code you are using to delete the autocad layer might be helpful.

Comment: I think the layer is assigned to drawing elements and thus you can't delete it. Same with trying to delete it from the `UI`.

Comment: Have you checked that there are no objects to be purged? If there are no objects to purge, you will need to post some more information but you are getting the error because there is _something_ in your drawing still referencing that layer.

Comment: For example - do you have any blocks? The blocks can be referenced on a different layer to the one you are trying to delete but within the block definition itself it can reference any number of different layers.

Answer (score 1):

The objects within your drawing will be represented on a particular layer. If any of the drawing objects still sit on that layer, you will not be able to delete it because those objects still reference the layer.

First, make sure that no objects are present on that layer. Next, if you have deleted objects from the layer you may also have to purge them from the drawing database before the layer can be deleted.

Also bear in mind that according to the [Developer Documentation](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/files/WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-3cee.htm) you cannot delete Layer 0, Defpoints or the current layer.